# "Failed to send message. Review message and try again" when sending SMS to short code from Samsung Galaxy Note8

Tags: samsung, sms

When trying to send SMS to short code recipients like 567676, 56161, etc. from Samsung Galaxy Note8, I got the following error message:

> Failed to send message. Review message and try again.

I've tried entering the correct SMSC number, allowing premium access, nothing has worked. I tried the SIM in another phone., I couldn't send it from there too.

I'm able to send SMS to normal phone numbers.

How to fix this?

Comment: Contact your carrier to see if it's included in your phone plan

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, turns out the problem was due to my mobile balance. I had unlimited recharge package which always showed 0 balance hence the messages were not going out for these kind of numbers that are chargeable. I recharged my mobile and voila, the message got sent.

Comment: Yes, you have to do a recharge. Do a General Top Up of the lowest denomination (Rs 30). Don't top up with SMS Vouchers. The SMS to 567676 would generally cost Rs 3/-.

Comment: "Unlimited pack is not applicable to call/sms for special numbers (starting 1860 and 567*****). For contacting special number you need to maintain minimum balance in your account( Rs. 05/-)." - From Airtel customer service today.